# Running Selenium browser inside linux server for Whitelisted URLs

Tags: python, linux, selenium, networking, firewall

We have provisioned for a Red Hat Linux Server to run the python api's for web scraping. This server is not open to all links outside the world. The URLs need to be white-listed to enable access on that site.

We have whitelisted itunes, Vudu.com and Target.com

When running the Selenium, we are able to successfully fetch from iTunes. But facing the following issues for Target and Vudu.

```
from selenium import webdriver
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1366,768))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

For iTunes,

```
driver.get("https://itunes.apple.com/us/movie/the-angry-birds-movie/id1100915157")
result = driver.find_element_by_class_name("price")
```

We can see the result successfully as,
[image]

For Target,

```
driver.get("http://www.target.com/p/the-angry-birds-movie-blu-ray-dvd/-/A-51194551")  
result = driver.find_element_by_class_name("price")
```

We are getting the following error. 
[image]

Explanation: 
In case of Target, webpage is getting loaded and the HTML was returned. But the issue is, there were some Api calls which will get run in the browser to #fetch price and other details. Those were getting blocked and didn’t get run. So the returned HTML content is only partial. So not able to find the labels #corresponding for Price. So we are getting NoSuchElementException.

For Vudu,

```
driver.get("http://www.vudu.com/movies/#!content/777662/The-Legend-of-Tarzan")         #This line itself fail.
```

Getting the following error, 
[image]

Explanation:
In case of Vudu, there were no response. Not even the partial HTML which we got in Target. It just indefinitely waits without throwing any error.  When we manually stop the execution we can see following error. On the highlighted line, it just waits for the response.

Not sure how to resolve this. We have already whitelisted target.com, vudu.com, api.target.com. But still same error.

Can anyone please help on this.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response..Got busy on another project....Is there any fix to solve this long-pending issues....I see some response few weeks before...But it was removed...Can anyone please help on this.